# LinQ - Parsing multiple values of HTML Page

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have one problem with LINQ to select multiple values from the HTML page,

where I have one page with some div tags, and I would like to read all the values and push into a List

but the list just reads the first element of HTML page - not other values, here what I did:

```
 List<HotelAvailability> hotels = (from roomNameVal in doc.Descendants("div")
                       from roomPriceVal in doc.Descendants("div")
                       from roomDes in doc.Descendants("div")
                       where roomNameVal.Attributes.Contains("id") && roomNameVal.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("type")
                       && roomPriceVal.Attributes.Contains("id") && roomPriceVal.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("price")
                       //where roomDes.Attributes.Contains("id") && roomDes.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("ui-accordion-1-panel-0")

                       select new HotelAvailability()
                       {
                           HN= roomNameVal.InnerText.Trim(),
                           Price = roomPriceVal.InnerText.Trim()

                       }).ToList()
            ;
        return hotels;
```

Here is my HTML Page:

```
         <h3>
                    <div id='type'>
                        r1
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                    <div id='price'>
                        784
                    </div>
                </h3>

       <h3>
                    <div id='type'>
                        r2
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                    <div id='price'>
                        44
                    </div>
                </h3>

        <h3>
                    <div id='type'>
                        Chambre standard 5 pers du <span class=''>03/03/2014</span> au <span class=''>05/03/2014 </span>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                    <div id='price'>
                        12
                    </div>
                </h3>
```

It just reads the first element.

Could anyone point me out where I did it wrong? Thank you

Comment: It would be great to see HTML you are parsing

Comment: Are you using HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: As I'm new to LINQ i'm not sure the code which I wrote is correct to get all values into a List or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select `h3` tags which have `div` children with `lib_presta` and `prix_presta` ids (or just select `//h3` tags if all these tags have hotel data):

```
var xpath = "//h3[div[@id='lib_presta'] and div[@id='prix_presta']]";
var hotels = from h3 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath)                 
             select new HotelAvailability {
                 HotelName = h3.SelectSingleNode("div[@id='lib_presta']").InnerText,
                 Price = h3.SelectSingleNode("div[@id='prix_presta']").InnerText
             };
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I could get those values, however I' still have one problem when I parse tags which doesnt have any id or value to indicate, could you please have a look at my question below. Thanks

Comment: @bluewonder you can select first paragraph from div without id attribute with this query `h3.SelectNode("div[not(@id)]/p")`. Also I think you should remove your answer, because that is not answer actually

Comment: so should I put it in the xpath query like this: `var rooms = (from r in doc.SelectNodes("//h3[div[@id='lib_presta'] and div[@id='prix_presta'] and div[not(@id)]/p]")` then  `RoomDes = r.SelectNodes("div[not(@id)]/p").ToString()` ? Thanks

Comment: @bluewonder you should not add `and div[not(@id)]/p]` if not all `h3` elements have this div without id. Also you should call SelectSingleNode: `RoomDes = r.SelectSingleNode("div[not(@id)]/p").InnerText`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sorry for my mistake, the new div tag which I want to get out the p, it is not inside the h3 tag, it's the next one after closing of h3. It is </h3> <div> <p> chambre de 20 m² </p>.... </div>

Comment: @bluewonder you can just get next sibling node `RoomDes = h3.NextSibling.SelectSingleNode("p").InnerText`. Also consider to query for node which wraps both h3 and div

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now it's ok to go. Could I ask you one question that in your opinion, which HTML Parser for .NET has the best performance in case of parsing a huge amount of HTML data, Thank you very much

Comment: @bluewonder I usually use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing html, you can try other tool and compare performance